# Decrypting Base64 RSA Cipher with CryptoPP

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have created the RSA keypair elsewhere in the same manner as shown in the [documentation.](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography)

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
RSA::PublicKey  publicKey(params);
```

Below is the decryption function which accepts a base64 encoded cipher, which was encrypted using the public key and encoded, and accepts the previously created private key as well. This also comes from the aforementioned [documentation.](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography)

```cpp
const string RSA_Helpers::decrypt(const string& base64_cipher, const CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey) const
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    string cleartext = "";
    AutoSeededRandomPool RNG;
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(privateKey);
    StringSource cleartext_str_src(base64_cipher, true, 
        new PK_DecryptorFilter(RNG, decryptor, new StringSink(cleartext))
    );

    return cleartext;
}
```

However, upon execution, an unhandled exception from CryptoPP is thrown on the line before the return:
`CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext at memory location . . .`

I have also tried decoding the cipher from base64, with no luck.

```cpp
const string RSA_Helpers::decrypt(const string& base64_cipher, const CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey) const
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    string cipher = "";
    StringSource decoder(base64_cipher, true, new Base64Decoder(new StringSink(cipher)));

    string cleartext = "";
    AutoSeededRandomPool RNG;
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(privateKey);
    StringSource cleartext_str_src(cipher, true, 
        new PK_DecryptorFilter(RNG, decryptor, new StringSink(cleartext))
    );

    return cleartext;
}
```

Any help as to how the cipher can be properly decrypted is appreciated.

Comment: The decoder is very permissive. The code looks OK, so possibly a problem with garbage in - garbage out? We cannot tell, we don't have the input. Maybe it is a dialect of base 64 such as base64url. Also, that doesn't seem to be the full stacktrace. Could be the wrong RSA mechanism too, but we don't have the specs either.

Comment: An example of the base64 cipher input is as follows: 

`H4dMvsAefLYYes21l+Fg+H5O7G+BjvvochP5NUqcR5AcwEYe/FBC4534Z/n/BXxZB+J4RPnxI8Xwb3SiSece+La75hbhyTJrQtkgInhaK79Z1EdJf32UNscF8Di+5D1jWFerDUwdZ6nt8b9Z1ZiArCXj/Bf+RvNETO92QIfeFB0=`

Could you elaborate on wrong RSA mechanism?

Comment: It could use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding instead of OAEP, or it can use a different hash algorithm (there are even more options for OAEP but those are not used / supported all that much). Oh, and you would get the same error if you'd use the wrong private key of course.

Comment: I see. I am fairly certain an invalid private key is not the issue at hand here; however, I will try looking into RSA mechanism discrepancies.

Comment: It turns out a discrepancy between RSA mechanisms was in fact the issue, thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: NP. So the code was indeed OK, it just didn't solve the problem :)